# Saving Annotations on MapView

Tags: arrays, swift3, mapkit, nsuserdefaults, mapkitannotation

Currently the app I am developing creates custom annotations, but when the user switches away from the page with the mapView they are all unloaded. I am saving them into a custom array but UserDefaults is not letting me save that array. Is there an easy way to preserve placed annotations or how would I get UserDefaults to save my array. My array is like this:

```
var mapAnnotations = [pinLocations]()
struct pinLocations {
    let latitude: Double
    let longnitude: Double
    let name: Double
    let time: String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your struct a class instead, deriving from NSObject, and adopt NSCoding by implementing `init?(coder:)` and `encode(with:)`. An array of this class can now be archived into an NSData and saved into UserDefaults by calling `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:)` (and the reverse by calling `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with:)`).

Comment: This is an example of an archivable custom class: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch23p798basicFileOperations/ch36p1053basicFileOperations/Person.swift